# how to create android widget using C# android in visual studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am trying to create widget for android devices. Searched a lot. But could not get a single sample or write up on how to create this in visual studio using C# android blank applications. My question is are widgets can only be created in Android Studio and not with visual studio using C# ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use Xamarin application from Microsoft, to write code in C#. Xamarin is available in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. The application is available for Windows and Mac OS. Xamarin is used to create hybrid applications.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Android widgets can be created using xamarin :

The following links can help you to create Android widgets using xamarin

https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/SimpleWidget/

http://www.spikie.be/post/2017/07/01/AndroidFloatingWidgetsInXamarin.html

Goodluck!

Happy coding.