# How to use activity_main layout as a widget on xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, widget

I have a xamarin project and my main purpose is creating a widget by using activity_main layout and my activity main layout includes tabbed pages such as Tab1 , Tab2 and Tab3 . That is why i want to show them on widget . According to my researches i need some xml file to create a widget on android . My xml file like this.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
      android:minResizeWidth="144dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main"/>
```

I added activity_main as a initialLayout and i did some arrangement in the bag. My appwidget class like this .

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "Widget")]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
    [MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/widget_word")]
    class AppWidget : AppWidgetProvider
    {
        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {             
            context.StartService(new Intent(context, typeof(UpdateService)));
        }
    }
```

My updateService like this .

```
 public override void OnStart(Intent intent, int startId)
        {
            // Build the widget update for today
            RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate(this);

            // Push update for this widget to the home screen
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(AppWidget)).Name);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this);
            manager.UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
        }




        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context)
        {
            // Build an update that holds the updated widget contents
            var updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            return updateViews;
        }
```

I am using fragments to display tab1 , tab2 , tab3 . If I add fragment axml file to the initialLayout it works fine . But it shows only tab1 . I feel like i should use activity_main to display 3 tabs on widget. Please help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create android widget using C# android in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107074/how-to-create-android-widget-using-c-sharp-android-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Unfortunately not my problem is adding activity_main layout into the widget directly.

Comment: What do you mean widget directly?

Comment: Activity_main layout includes tab components. I want to show them as a widget.

Comment: each tab as a separate widget? So you want to create 3 applications if you have 3 tabs?

Comment: No i have just one widget. Activity_main includes three tab pages

Comment: Did you get error `Problem Loading Widget`? When you put appwidget to the desktop and `android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main"` ? If so, please double check elements you used in your activity_main, it is just support these widget class https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout  If you used viewPager or PagerSlidingTabStrip, it cannot be allowed.

Comment: Yes , i am taking an error when i put appwidget to the desktop . I will research elements right now .

Comment: Do you have any information about using bottomNavigationView on widget ? Because widget is not loaded because of bottomNavigationView . Other elements are perfectly working.

Comment: You cannot use `bottomNavigationView`, If you want to display a widget, you just allow to use remote layout(`FrameLayout`,`LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout`,`GridLayout`) and following widget classes(`AnalogClock`,`Button`,`Chronometer`,`ImageButton`,`ImageView`,`ProgressBar`,`TextView`,`ViewFlipper`,`ListView`,`GridView`,`StackView`,`AdapterViewFlipper`), I put the `bottomNavigationView` in the `LinearLayout` it still cannot show the widget when put it to the desktop.

Comment: You are right . I will change my strategy right now . I am planning to use buttons instead of bottomNavigationView . Thanks a lot . It was  a good experience for me .

Comment: You are welcome, can I post comment to answer? It will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `bottomNavigationView` in the `appwidget`,

If you set it you will get follow error.

[image]

Creating the App Widget layout is simple if you're familiar with Layouts. However, you must be aware that App Widget layouts are based on `RemoteViews`, which do not support every kind of layout or view widget.

A `RemoteViews` object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

`FrameLayout`
`LinearLayout`
`RelativeLayout`
`GridLayout`

And the following widget classes:

`AnalogClock`
`Button`
`Chronometer`
`ImageButton`
`ImageView`
`ProgressBar`
`TextView`
`ViewFlipper`
`ListView`
`GridView`
`StackView`
`AdapterViewFlipper`

Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Here is Google article about it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout